# how to fill color in white spaces using touch event?

Tags: iphone, ios4

[image]

want to fill all white spaces with different color using touch events

Right now i able to fill circles picking colors from picker but how to fill the intigrated part with different color......

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UIColor *cl=[UIColor clearColor];
    UITouch *tuch=[touches anyObject];
    if ([clr isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {
        cl=[UIColor redColor];
    }
    else if ([clr isEqualToString:@"Blue"]) {
        cl=[UIColor blueColor] ;
    }
    else if ([clr isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {
        cl=[UIColor greenColor];
    }


    CGPoint p = [tuch locationInView:self];
    float xsq1=p.x -50;
    xsq1=xsq1*xsq1;
    float ysq1=p.y-110;
    ysq1=ysq1*ysq1;
    float h1 = ABS(sqrt(xsq1 + ysq1));

    float xsq2=p.x -100;
    xsq2=xsq2*xsq2;
    float ysq2=p.y-110;
    ysq2=ysq2*ysq2;
    float h2 = ABS(sqrt(xsq2 + ysq2));

    float xsq3=p.x -50;
    xsq3=xsq3*xsq3;
    float ysq3=p.y-190;
    ysq3=ysq3*ysq3;
    float h3 = ABS(sqrt(xsq3 + ysq3));

    if (h1<=40) {
        NSLog(@"touches inside of first circle");
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, cl.CGColor);
        CGRect cir1 = CGRectMake(10,266,80,80);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, cir1);
        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:cir1];
    }
    else if (h2<=40) {
        NSLog(@"touches inside of second circle");
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, cl.CGColor);
        CGRect cir2 = CGRectMake(60,266,80,80);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, cir2);
        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:cir2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use following link its may be used u http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015667/applying-alpha-outside-intersection-of-2-cgpath-objects

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Can you give a step-by-step explanation of where the user would touch, and a picture showing what parts should be colored?

Comment: in the above image if i click on any white space it should be colored with some color

Comment: I count 8 separate spaces in that picture, including the part outside of all the circles.  How many do you count?

Comment: u r correct 8 only, have to color each part with different color using touch and one more thing that not an image we  have to draw that circles also

Answer (score 1):

There are two tasks here, the first is to detect which region has been touched, the second is to fill that region. Both require you to calculate the circle intersection points of the above image using trigonometry, and to know their positions.

A simple solution to the touch region detection would be to check if the touch is contained in any of the circles, this is easily calculated by calculating the distance to the touch point from the circles centre, if it is less than the radius it is inside the circle. If it is inside more than one circle, you know it belongs in that intersection region. It if is inside no circles, but the x component is in between the centre of a left circle and a right circle it must be in the region in between all the circles. Otherwise the touch point must be outside all of the circles.

In order to fill the various sections of the above image, you can create paths containing the regions you need to fill and fill them with `CGContextFillPath`. Something like this:

```
// draw a path to contain the fill region
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, startx, starty);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, ...);

// lots of other CGContextAddArcToPoint or AddLineToPoint method calls here to define the clip region

// close the clip path
CGContextClosePath(ctx);

// now you can fill the region
CGContextFillPath(ctx);
```

You can repeat this for as many paths as you like. You can calculate the path arcs to use from the circle intersection points and radii.